# Swift function calling itself

Tags: swift, function, func

Could anyone explain why this results in 2 instead of 3?

```
func fib(n: Int) -> Int {

   return n < 2 ? n : (fib(n: n-1) + (fib(n: n-2))

}

print(fib(n: 3))
```

Comment: You need to debug. It's not related to SwiftUI, so no need for that tag. Start by breaking the ternary if, make multiple lines, and use intermediary variables and add prints?

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through your code.

```
print(fib(n: 3))
```

Here, you're passing in `3` for `n`. Because `3` is **not** less than `2`, the second half of the ternary operator is evaluated:

```
///    1.             2.
return (fib(n: n-1) + (fib(n: n-2))
```

1. For `fib(n: n-1)`, you're passing in `2` for `n`. `2` is once again **not** less than `2`, so `return (fib(n: n-1) + (fib(n: n-2))` is evaluated another time. This translates to `return (fib(n: 1) + (fib(n: 0))`, which will become `return (1 + 0)`.
2. For `fib(n: n-2)`, you're passing in `1` for `n`. `1` **is** less than `2`, so the return just becomes `return n`.

1 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we can write this function like this to make it easier to understand:

```
func fib(n: Int) -> Int {
    if n < 2 {
        return n
    }
    return fib(n: n-1) + fib(n: n-2)
}
```

So, when we pass in `3` as parameter, it will return `fib(2) + fib(1)`.

Here, `fib(2)` will return `fib(1) + fib(0)`, which is `1 + 0 = 1`; and `fib(1)` will return `1`.

Thus, the final outcome will be `1 + 1 = 2`.